# How To Find MA and Turn it into Massachusetts and put into column called state name

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

For my class, We have a table where States are listed as their abbreviations and I need to list the Full State name and abbreviation, but I'm unsure of how to get MA to Massachusets. I am unsure of what I would use to have it be transformed into what I need. Any help would be great thanks!
It is all one table that contains ZIP, CITY, STATE.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Is it just one table? Is there an additional column that you are working with?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a case statement as follows (assuming you don't have a column that has the full version):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state = 'MA' THEN 'Massachusets' END AS state_name 
FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be another table which contains abbreviations and full names. Then you'd **join** those tables. For example:

```
create table full_state
  (state             varchar2(2)   constraint pk_fullstat primary key,
   full_state_name   varchar2(50)  not null
  );

insert into full_state (state, full_state_name) 
  select 'AL', 'Alabama' from dual union all
  select 'AK', 'Alaska'  from dual union all
  ...
  select 'WY', 'Wyoming' from dual;
```

Then you'd

```
select s.zip, s.city, s.state, t.full_state_name
from state s join full_state t on t.state = s.state;
```

---

Another option is to "hardcode" those names (but that's most probably wrong). You can use `CASE` or `DECODE` for that:

```
select s.zip, s.city, s.state,
  case when s.state = 'AL' then 'Alabama'
       when s.state = 'AK' then 'Alaska'
       ...
       when s.state = 'MA' then 'Massachusets'
       ...
       when s.state = 'WY' then 'Wyoming'
  end as full_state_name
from state s
```

or

```
select s.zip, s.city, s.state,
  decode(s.state, 'AL', 'Alabama', 
                  'AK', 'Alaska', 
                  ...
                  'WY', 'Wyoming'
        ) as full_state_name
from state s
```

As you can see, this option is *awful* as it requires you to specify all states, in all queries, every time you're about to fetch full state name. Therefore - create a new table for states.